# Categorize and structure database

Tags: php, mysql, structure, categories

I've been pondering the best way to approach the structure of this database. What I have so far is:

table **category**

- cat_id (PK)
- title

table **sub_cat**

- sc_id (PK)
- cat_id (FK)
- title

This is all fine since I could use it as follows:

- Car -> Mazda
- computer hardware -> CPU
- clothing -> Male :: Pants
- Car Parts -> Mazda :: Spoilers
- ...

The problem is how could I best structure the database to further utilize the best of each category. The cars data will require a lot of fields suitable for cars alone which another category may require something completely different.

It should be said there will be a lot of categories.

Comment: This is a very interesting article about a nested structure that might help you out: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: This method looks complicated.. Challenge accepted! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible is to create a table 'Details', built something like this

```
= ItemId === DetailId === DetailValue =
| Somecar1 | 1         |  Blue        |
| Somecar2 | 2         |  Four        |
| Somecar2 | 1         |  Pink        |
| Somecar2 | 2         |  Two         |
=======================================
```

Where DetailId refers to something like this, detailreference;

```
= CategoryId === DetailId === DetailString =
| 1           |  1         | Color         |
| 1           |  2         | Doors         |
============================================
```

If you want to get the info of Somecar1, you should query the Details table for the data, then query detailreference to get the type of detail stored inside of a certain number, for a certain category.